# TypeError: only size-1 arrays are converted to Python scalars when trying to iterate through pixels

Tags: python, rgb, opencv

I am trying iterate through pixels in the image and get their R, G, B values.

```
import cv2

frame = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
height, width, c = frame.shape

for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        color = int(frame[x, y])
        print(color)
```

But I am getting TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars, on this line

```
color = int(frame[x, y])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `color = (frame[x, y,:])` so that you get the 3 coordinates.

**[Edit]**

This actually works for me while casting into `int`:

```
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        color_raw = (frame[x, y,:])
        color = list(map(int, color_raw))
        print(color)
```

Comment: I don't want to change the question, but do you relaly need to cast them into `int`?

Comment: I am only need to get the rgb values from pixels. So maybe I don't need to cast them into int.

Comment: Check the edit I did, it works even with the int @Alechandro

Answer (score 0):

The issue with what you're doing is that you are trying to convert a frame into an int, which is not possible. I'd recommend using Pillow instead of cv2. You can use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to get the RGB value of a given pixel in an image. It is easy to use and supports Python 3.8.